# Nijigasaki: is yuri flavor different between anime and game

Tags: love-live

I am curious on how much of the anime is original, and what's based on the game?

- Is the yuri flavor amplified in the anime?
- Are the anime official yuri couplings the same as the game?
- Are the relationship between Ayumu and "you" similar to what was in the game?